# PictureBox Image assignment leads to Paint event loop

Tags: vb.net, winforms, picturebox

I am creating a `Bitmap` to load into a `PictureBox` during the `Paint` event like this:-

```
Private Sub MyBox_Paint (ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                         ByVal e      As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBox.Paint
    MyBox.Image = FunctionReturningBitMap (MyBox.Width, MyBox.Height)
End Sub
```

This causes the bitmap to appear on the picture box as intended, but for some reason causes the `Paint` event to be invoked again, leading to a tight loop. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have also tried the above but handling the `MyBox.Invalidated` event. The result is the same.

Comment: defo not another method invoking paint like mouse move over PictureBox possibly? And it seems perfectly reasonable that .NET will call Paint after assigning the Image. Also I can only assume that it is computationally costly to assign the contents of a PictureBox in the Paint event, considering how often it may be called by .NET. On a debug run try commenting out the assign line after the first iterations, to test if it is the Image call itself causing the Paint to be invoked

Comment: @ColinSteel, I checked that no mousy events were taking place (by reducing the dialogue to a small size and keeping everything else away from it). It doesn't appear that's the reason. Commenting out the call on subsequent iterations stopped the tight loop (and the bitmap still appeared). So it appears that it is the assignment causing the event. This suggests some ghastly hack involving the time interval between calls might fix it.

Comment: A time check or bool set will do, but I must ask why setting the entire Image on the Paint event. What is the image and what changes on each Paint

Comment: @ColinSteel, the image is a diagram. It will need to be redrawn if the user resizes the dialogue, and also if the picturebox is obscured by some other application and then exposed again, or if the dialogue is moved. All the usual stuff, really, except that it isn't currently happening. I am given to understand that invalidating the picture box (and thus forcing a Paint event) is the way to do this.

Comment: No. Nothing will need to be redrawn if it is covered over by another window or moved, only when resized, make a resized event for the PictureBox and put the Image assignment in there, remove the Image assignment from the Paint event. Only use the Paint event (and the proper PaintEventArgs that should be with it) to draw over the Image temporarily (like cross-hairs over the mouse pointer etc...). If the Image is becoming distorted/missing after another form has covered it there is something wrong beyond the PictureBox

Comment: @ColinSteel, righto. Looks like I've been barking up the wrong tree, then. I'll give what you suggest a try. Thank you for your help.